# How do I loop through an array while also setting if/else conditions in LC3

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, input, lc3

I'm working on some code with the intention of looping through an array of prime numbers from 0-99, and then returning "1" if the user input is found inside of the array. Otherwise returning "0".
Here's some pseudocode of what I wan't my program to do:

```
Array = [all prime numbers from 0-99]
if userinput = Array[i]:
    print "1"
else:
    print "0"
```

In terms of LC3, here's what I've come to so far:

```
.ORIG x3000
LD R2, PRIMENUMBERS   

PRIMENUMBERS .fill x6000

.orig x6000
.fill 2
.fill 3
.fill 5
.fill 7
.fill 11
.fill 13
.fill 17
.fill 19
.fill 23
.fill 29
.fill 31
.fill 37
.fill 41
.fill 43
.fill 47
.fill 53
.fill 59
.fill 61
.fill 67
.fill 71
.fill 73
.fill 79
.fill 83
.fill 89
.fill 97

.END
```

I can't seem to understand how to go through the elements in the array and I don't know how I'd make the if/else statements, including how to receive user input.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code needs to include a loop.  What is `i` for example?

Suggest to write your algorithm/pseudo code in C *and test it to make sure it works* — it is a lot of work to debug a design flaw or algorithmic flaw in assembly.  (Put another way, its hard to take broken pseudo code to assembly language.)  And other languages offer capabilities that make it harder to see what needs to be done in assembly language.

When translating pseudo code into assembly language, translate all the variables first, then work on the code.

Control structures like loops, if-then-else statements, etc.. nest in high level language, and they nest just as nicely in assembly language despite their expansion into multiple lines & labels, and without the benefit of {}'s and/or indentation.

When we have an if statement nested inside a for loop, then we can translate the if statement first or the for loop first — it doesn't matter.  Just keep the orientation such that the complete if statement is nested inside the body of the loop, just as it is in C.

Comment: Oh yea, i forgot to add a for loop to the pseudocode that runs through all elements in the array.
I'm just having trouble implementing high level code into LC3 code

Comment: Start with working & tested high level code, seriously.  How long could that take, 5min- 15min?  I know it sounds like a methodical approach, separating *algorithm design* from *assembly programming*, but this decomposition makes the whole problem simpler, whereas doing both together in assembly (or starting with an incomplete or not working pseudo code) while your learning assembly makes everything harder especially debugging.  For example, one reason you don't know where to start b/c your pseudo code is just a fragment, a hint, of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I advocate decomposition of the problem, into smaller parts so that each part is solvable, by searching, by trying, or by asking on the internet.  Decomposing a problem like this starts by separating algorithm design and pseudo code from the translation of it to assembly.  Get that part right and the translation goes smoother.  When translating, you don't need to do the whole thing at once, you can do one step at a time (for example, break down a for loop into piece parts), so, more decomposition.  This will not slow you down, but rather make you faster (and you'll gain genuine insight).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is two sheets of paper, one to draw memory places and names of register and what they are pointing to and/or the value.
Second sheet to write your code, start in the middle you will have to add code above and below.

Ahh i forgot a rubber (most important) and pencil!

First think at the very last moment when comparing the value entered and one element in the table
Draw it (1st sheet) does it seem correct ? Code it! (2nd sheet)
At this point you can test a short program comparing a value with something somewhere in the memory and output a message
you now have to loop thru all your elements especially between the 1st and last one, check and recheck if one is not omitted

Draw how you point thru those elements, answer when you have to stop: be carrefull
You have nearly complete the second part of your program
Now the first one
How to collect the number? Try one digit first, is it a char or a number? How to transform one into the other? You can test this part alone
Get multiple caracters, convert (be carrefull), compare by looping into your table

It's a very bad idea to code the table's address. Let the assembler do the job!

PRIMENUMBERS .fill 2
and use LEA Rn,PRIMENUMBERS